# Push Back This Pointer into private static Member Vector

Tags: c++, static, this

I want to push-back the object itself to the class's static member variable. However i get "unresolved external symbol". My Idea is to collect selected Objects in a Container.

```
class ActionClass
{
public:
    ActionClass();
    ~ActionClass();
    int addAction();

private:
    static std::vector<ActionClass* const> instances;
};

int ActionClass::addAction()
{
    instances.push_back(this);
    return 0;
}

ActionClass::ActionClass()
{
}

ActionClass::~ActionClass()
{
}
```

Comment: Search for, and read about, the difference between *declaring* a variable, and *defining* a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define this static variable in one of cpp files:

```
std::vector<ActionClass* const> ActionClass::instances;
```